# Animate a line between <li> items

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have created a little timeline with CSS.

Basically, it creates a vertical line between list items using `::before`.

My next step is to try and animate that line with a colour fill from top to the current selected list item.

I don't know if it's possible based on my mark-up but I thought someone here might give me some ideas.

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

nav li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  /* Color of the line */
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #272727;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.first {
  top: -70px;
}

.second {
  top: -20px;
}

.fourth {
  top: 30px
}

.last {
  top: 50px;
}

.circle {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: height 0.5s ease;
  transition: width 0.5s ease;
}

.rect {
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: #272727;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s, width 1s;
  -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s, width 1s;
  transition: transform 0.6s, width 1s;
}

nav a:hover,
nav .active-section {
  color: #9b59b6;
}

nav a:hover span,
nav .active-section span {
  background-color: #29aae2;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#section1">
        <span class="icon first"><img src="https://tstdev.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/Mouse.svg"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#section2">
        <span class="rect"></span>
        <span class="circle second"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#section3">
        <span class="rect"></span>
        <span class="circle third"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#section4">
        <span class="rect"></span>
        <span class="circle fourth"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#section5">
        <span class="rect"></span>
        <span class="circle last"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

There is also some JavaScript, which adds the scroll to section and adds an active class to the anchor link.

A working example can be found here: https://codepen.io/Jonny-Quinn/pen/RwEEMod

Any ideas would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m ..my issue is i want it to fill between the <li> items partially, not completely fill, depending on if the <li> has an active state ..

Comment: @freedomn-m I think you misunderstood me. It's not obvious in my code above that there is a vertical line joining all <li> elements ... I assumed maybe you hadn't seen the link to codepen